# Main Sub Calling Multiple of the Same U-D Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have four functions and one main Sub that is called upon clicking a button. Within that Sub I have several lines, calling the same functions to take in different parameters for each one.

My question is, is this bad practice? I can't think of any other way to call these functions because I *need* them all taking in their own user-defined parameters. It just looks odd is all.

Take this as an example:

```
Sub Generate_Timeline_Click()

Dim timelineWb As Workbook
Dim RegExp As Object
Dim regexObj As Object
Dim logSheetRange As Range, logCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowItTook As Long, lastRowStartedProcessing As Long, lastRowProcessingTheFollowing As Long, x As Long
Dim processStartSearch As String, firstAddress As String
Dim counter As Integer, j As Integer, i As Integer
```

...etc...

```
   Call Call_Line_Search("Started Processing", startedProcessingLinesWs, lastRow)
   lastRowStartedProcessing = startedProcessingLinesWs.Cells(startedProcessingLinesWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Call Call_Line_Search("Processing the following", processTheFollowingLinesWs, lastRow)
   lastRowProcessingTheFollowing = processTheFollowingLinesWs.Cells(processTheFollowingLinesWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Call Call_Line_Search("Signal Data Call Received", signalDataCallLinesWs, lastRow)
   Call Call_Line_Search("It took: ", itTookLinesWs, lastRow)
   lastRowItTook = itTookLinesWs.Cells(itTookLinesWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", startedProcessingLinesWs, lastRowStartedProcessing, "B")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", startedProcessingLinesWs, lastRowStartedProcessing, "C")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", processTheFollowingLinesWs, lastRowProcessingTheFollowing, "C")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", processTheFollowingLinesWs, lastRowProcessingTheFollowing, "D")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", processTheFollowingLinesWs, lastRowProcessingTheFollowing, "E")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", processTheFollowingLinesWs, lastRowProcessingTheFollowing, "B")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", itTookLinesWs, lastRowItTook, "B")
   Call Parse_Data(regexObj, "[regex pattern]", itTookLinesWs, lastRowItTook, "C")

End Sub
```

And below I have all of my functions and such.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). While this question is better suited for Code Review, I can say that this is a normal practice in general. In fact, I just wrote a similar bit of code about 15 minutes ago! :). That said, you can remove the `Call` statement, because it's not necessary. Also, if your procedures are not returning any values, they are not really functions, but subs. The best procedures are those that are short sweet and do one thing *very* well.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Fair enough. Thanks, Scott! These functions are basically scanning through a log that's been imported, finding specific statements and then performing some substrings. Data is being written to cells in a number of worksheets, these should be functions? Haven't done any programming in a while and have just started learning VBA.

Comment: These are not `Function`s (but `Sub`s) as @ScottHoltzman mentioned. Also, what you have written is not a UDF - which is a function that is written intended to return a value and place it in a cell **when called from that cell**.  You might get some efficiencies by converting the `Sub`s to `Function`s. To post in CodeReview you must show all of the real working code with an explanation of the real intent of the code.

Comment: @AJD It seems i've been misunderstanding what a UDF is, but you summed that up and it makes a bit more sense now. How would one actually call the `Function` from a cell? I guess that what i've done was not technically return a value, but just move values around? Which would technically not "return" a value. Think that's why i've been a bit confused on that.

Comment: @RunningEXE - Typically functions return a value. Think like `=SUM(1,2)`. You can write a custom function - often called a `UDF` - that returns a value from given input (or even with no input). You can also write a custom function that is not called by cells and is used solely in code. All this is kind of semantics in a way, but learning how to "speak the language" will help you communicate your issues to others more clearly :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Gotcha, thanks again!!